# Function to recognize the end of a page won't split the text correctly

Tags: c++, text, sfml

I'm trying to write a simple quest log program in c++ and SFML - something like quest logs in RPG games. I'm stuck at the state/function responsible for displaying all the entries in a single quest. I want it to work like an e-book reader, meaning when opening a quest, the pages (and std::vector) are filled with all the entries and only 2 neighboring ones are displayed at any giving time. First i had to put a function that would recognize when the horizontal end of the page is reached and this works just fine

Result of horizontal breaking:

[image]

but when i added a function to recognize when an entry hits the vertical end of the page, this is what happens

Result of horizontal + vertical breaking:

[image]

Here's the code for the function filling the pages

```
if (!mPagesFilled)
{
    //make sure container of pages is not empty
    if(mPages.empty())
        mPages.push_back(Page());

    for (auto it : mViewedQuest->questEntries) //main loop - iterate through entries belonging to a single, selected quest
    {
        //if there is less than 100px left, add a new Page() to a vector mPages
        if (mActiveTheme->pageLayout[mLeftRight].height - mPages.back().pageSize.y < 100)
        {
            mPages.push_back(Page());
            if (mLeftRight == 0)
                mLeftRight = 1;
            else
                mLeftRight = 0;
        }

        //create and initialize the temporary PageEntry buffer object
        PageEntry entry;
        entry.header.setFont(mActiveTheme->themeFont);
        entry.header.setPosition(mActiveTheme->pageLayout[mLeftRight].left, mActiveTheme->pageLayout[mLeftRight].top + mPages.back().pageSize.y);
        entry.header.setString(it.getEntryDate());
        entry.header.setColor(sf::Color(50, 50, 50, 255));
        entry.entryHeight = entry.header.getLocalBounds().height + 20 ; //update entry height

        //set up the body of entry
        entry.body.setFont(mActiveTheme->themeFont);
        entry.body.setColor(sf::Color::Black);
        entry.body.setPosition(mActiveTheme->pageLayout[mLeftRight].left, mActiveTheme->pageLayout[mLeftRight].top + entry.entryHeight + mPages.back().pageSize.y);

        //clear the stream and the buffer string and put the iterated entry content into the stream
        ss.clear();
        mBuffer.clear();
        ss << it.entryText;

        while (ss) //loop for as long as there is something to be read from the stream
        {
            //check if we have reached the end of stream and break the loop if we did to avoid the garbage char at the end
            mBufferChar = ss.peek(); 
            if (mBufferChar == EOF)
                continue; // i know technically it should be break; but since it's EOF than it doesn't really matter i think

            //append the buffer string with the next char from the stream and update the body
            mBuffer += ss.get();
            entry.body.setString(mBuffer);

            //check if we have hit the right side of the page and add newline if we did
            if (entry.body.getLocalBounds().width > mActiveTheme->pageLayout[mLeftRight].width)
            {
                size_t it = mBuffer.find_last_of(" "); //check where was the last space in the string
                mBuffer.insert(it, "\n"); //put a newline there
                entry.body.setString(mBuffer); //update body string

                //after putting the newline update the height by one line height (represented by header height, always one line) and update pagesize
                entry.entryHeight += entry.header.getLocalBounds().height;
                mPages.back().pageSize.y += entry.entryHeight;


                //check if entry has reached the end of page
                if (mActiveTheme->pageLayout[mLeftRight].height - mPages.back().pageSize.y < 100)
                {
                    //if yes mark entry as unfinished, push it into the page, and reset the height of the buffer entry
                    entry.isFinished = false;
                    mPages.back().page.push_back(entry);
                    entry.entryHeight = 0;

                    //push a new page and toggle the pagemark
                    mPages.push_back(Page());
                    if (mLeftRight == 0)
                        mLeftRight = 1;
                    else
                        mLeftRight = 0;

                    //move the entry to the other page, clear the string buffer and the body string
                    entry.body.setPosition(mActiveTheme->pageLayout[mLeftRight].left, mActiveTheme->pageLayout[mLeftRight].top + entry.entryHeight + mPages.back().pageSize.y);
                    mBuffer.clear();
                    entry.body.setString("");
                    entry.header.setString("");
                }

            } //once entry passes these to if statements go on with the next stream chars until once again right side of the page is reached
        }

        //all stream chars read, mark entry as finished and push it to the page
        entry.isFinished = true;
        mPages.back().page.push_back(entry);

    }
    //all entries parsed, mark filled flag true
    mPagesFilled = true;
}
else
{ }
```

I suspect i had to mess something because now even after commenting out the part for vertical breaking the result is very similar to the 2nd picture, but can't seem to find the error. Quick breakdown:

> 1. mActiveTheme->pageLayout[mLeftRight] - this is a vector of sf::IntRect
>      objects that specify the position of pages in a selected theme and
>      mLeftRight is an int variable keeping track of whether at the moment a
>      left or right page is being used
> 2. Entry object is a struct of a date and std::string and mViewedQuest->questEntries is a vector of Entry objects
> 3. mPages is a vector of PageEntry objects, these in turn are structs containing the following

```
PageEntry()
{

};

sf::Text header;   //header containing the date of an Entry
sf::Text body;     //entry text
int entryHeight;   //stores the current height of the object 
bool isFinished;   //indicator if an entry is split among pages or not
```

> 4. ss is a stringstream
> 5. pageSize in mPages.back().pageSize is an sf::Vector2i storing the height of all PageEntry objects contained withing a single page

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger and/or add some debug output, to see which value get set wrong, when and where?

Comment: @Lukas unfortunately I don't know how to use a debugger. Whenever i encounter issues I tend to use extensive debug console output although in this instance I didn't have an idea how to apply this. I'll try printing entry size and page size after every iteration, see what i can find. I already found 1 error though - when vertical break occurs at tha last line of the entry i dont update the new page's size and the header of the next entry overlaps with it

Comment: @Lukas i added debugging printfs to the console and i noticed another bug

 mPages.back().pageSize.y += entry.entryHeight;

this caused pageSize to outgrow the sum of entries. Changed it to 

mPages.back().pageSize.y += entry.header.getLocalBounds().height;

entries now properly reach the end of the page (more or less) but the text overlaps another piece of the text in many places. Probably something with when and how a new page is pushed back to the mPages vector

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the time to really go through all of your code. Since to me it seems more like a "math" problem than anything else, it might be helpful to do the math once on paper and then check with the code or similar.